Understanding 責務と待遇が伴う無期限契約
This is the definition for 正規雇用

せいきこよう【正規雇用】
一つの企業に所属する者として相応の責務と待遇が伴う無期限契約の雇用形態。一般にフルタイムで働く。⇔非正規雇用。

I am confused about 責務と待遇が伴う無期限契約 part. It seems like 無期限契約 is either an object for 伴う or a target for 伴う. I assume in this context that 無期限契約 is the "main thing", so it is a target for 伴う. It can be rewritten as 責務と待遇を伴う無期限契約, right?

This is a rare verb that is not Sino-Japanese and works both transitively and intransitively.
The original sentence before it was converted into that clause-modified noun phrase would be 無期限契約に責務と待遇が伴う, where 伴う is used as an intransitive verb and 責務 and 待遇 are its subjects.
無期限契約が責務と待遇を伴う is also grammatical. Here 伴う is used as a transitive verb. There is not much difference in meaning. Either way, they come together.
